# Variable bmr might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMR

{
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    //object to use the keyboard input methods

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



    //ask the user to provide input

    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");

    String name = in.next();

    System.out.print("Gender (M of F): ");

    String gender = in.next();

    System.out.print("Enter your age: ");

    String age = in.next();

    System.out.print("Height in inches: ");

    String height = in.next();

    System.out.println("Weight in pounds: ");

    String weight = in.next();

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println();




    //convert measurements to metric units

    double ageNum = Double.parseDouble(age);

    double heightNum = Double.parseDouble(height);

    double weightNum = Double.parseDouble(weight);

    double heightCm = heightNum * 2.54;

    double weightKilo = weightNum * 0.453592;



    //calculate the BMR for males or females

    double bmr;

    if ( gender == "M" )
        bmr = (13.397 * weightKilo) + (4.799 * heightCm) - (5.677 * ageNum) + 88.362;

    else if ( gender == "F" )
        bmr = (9.247 * weightKilo) + (3.098 * heightCm) - (4.330 * ageNum) + 447.593;

    else 
        System.out.println("Please enter either M or F. I apologize for the gender binary.");

    //display output

    System.out.println("Calculate Your Basal Metabolism");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Name: " + name);

    System.out.println("Gender: " + gender);

    System.out.println("Age: " + age);

    System.out.println("Weight (kg): " + weightKilo);

    System.out.println("Height (cm): " + heightCm);

    System.out.println("Basal Metabolic Rate: " + bmr + " calories per day");





}
}
```

I had to write this code for my online class to calculate the someone's Basal Metabolic rate. Every time I run it I get an error saying that the variable bmr might not have been initialized. But I did initialize it in my conditional statements. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You need to initialize bmr, as indicated by the error message, you have only declared it.Initialize it as  double bmr=0.0;

Comment: Search for the error: [\[java\] variable might not have been initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+variable+might+not+have+been+initialized) and you will find *many* duplicates. Actually, don't even search. Just look at the related questions - might as well do it now since the suggestions were apparently ignored when creating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double bmr;` change to  `double bmr=0;`

you did not initialize your local variable.

There is another mistake in your code. `gender` is a `String` and you are comparing `String` using `==` it is wrong. you should use `equals()`

use

```
if("M".equals(gender))
```

instead of

```
if ( gender == "M" )
```

Comment: When I put `double bmr=0` and then execute the program it doesn't calculate the bmr at all, it just stays 0.

Comment: @user3094477 see my rest of the answer. Your `if` conditional not satisfied since your code issue in `==` with `String`. use `if("M".equals(gender))`;

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
double bmr = 0.0;
```

BTW, you should also use:

```
"M".equals(gender)
```

instead of

```
gender == "M"
```

This error occurs because if gender is not `"M"` or `"F"`, `bmr` will not be initialized when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

> Local variables and primitives should be initialized before use
>   because you would know what to expect from the values. Historically,
>   when a new variable was created it would contain random values from
>   the memory [and one could not predict the value]. Java also requires
>   this because it prevents the presence of orphaned variables.

**change**

```
double bmr;
```

**to**

```
double bmr=0;
```

**Also use**

```
if("M".equals(gender))
```

**instead of**

```
if ( gender == "M" )
```

Answer (score 0):

As per java syntax rule, method local variables should be initialized. You have not initialized your local variable. So change:

```
double bmr ;
```

to

```
double bmr = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you do not initialize all local variables.

In your case you have to make following change:

```
double bmr = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a value to the variable before use it **in all cases**.

In the last else bmr is not initialized, but probably you don't want to display the output if the gender is not entered, so, you can add a return clause in the else to avoid it.

```
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter either M or F. I apologize for the gender binary.");
        return;
    }
```

If you want to show the output also in this case you have to provide a valure to bmt:

```
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter either M or F. I apologize for the gender binary.");
        bmr = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double bmr;  //initialization is not necessary here if we use following way around

    if ( gender == "M" )
    { 
        bmr = (13.397 * weightKilo) + (4.799 * heightCm) - (5.677 * ageNum) + 88.362;
        System.out.println(bmr); //we are using bmr but after initialization in above line. So compiler doesn't complain.
    }
```

above code is pretty ok when you are using `bmr` at the left side of the `=` sign and you can use to print its value after initialization. It is mandatory to initialize variable before using it.

but in following  scenario bmr has not been initialize before using it.

```
double bmr;

    if ( gender == "M" )
    { 
        System.out.println(bmr); //compiler complains here
    }
```

to correct it initialize `bmr` to some value,

```
 double bmr=111;

        if ( gender == "M" )
        { 
            System.out.println(bmr);
        }
```

Now let's check incorrect code from your code snippet.

```
double bmr; 
System.out.println("Basal Metabolic Rate: " + bmr + " calories per day"); //you have written this line next after 13 to 14 lines of code after `bmr` declaration where compiler complains for initialization;
```